# Odoo 8 qweb report style modification

Tags: css, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to modify my qweb report contents in Oddo 8 I am using  div position. I want to hide fax field on print view. How can i do? It is not working.I am trying to css like display none.

Here below is my code
this is my final code

```
<openerp>
<data>
    <template id="report_picking_inherit_demo" inherit_id="stock.report_picking">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('page')]/div[hasclass('row')]" position="replace">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div t-if="o.picking_type_id.code=='incoming' and o.partner_id">
                    <span>
                        <strong>Supplier Address:</strong>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div t-if="o.picking_type_id.code=='internal' and o.partner_id">
                    <span>
                        <strong>Warehouse Address:</strong>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div t-if="o.picking_type_id.code=='outgoing' and o.partner_id">
                    <span>
                        <strong>Customer Addresswww:</strong>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div t-if="o.partner_id" name="partner_header">
                      <div t-field="o.partner_id"
                     t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone"], "no_marker": true}'/>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
                <div t-if="o.move_lines and o.move_lines[0].partner_id and o.move_lines[0].partner_id.id != o.partner_id.id">
                    <span>
                        <strong>Delivery Address:</strong>
                    </span>
                    <div t-field="o.move_lines[0].partner_id"
                         t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone","fax"], "no_marker": true}'/>
                </div>
                <div t-if="o.picking_type_id.code != 'internal' and (not o.move_lines or not o.move_lines[0].partner_id) and o.picking_type_id.warehouse_id.partner_id">
                    <span>
                        <strong>Warehouse Address:</strong>
                    </span>
                    <div t-field="o.picking_type_id.warehouse_id.partner_id"
                         t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone","fax"], "no_marker": true}'/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</data>
```

Here I entered fax something example
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIUCo.png

after that this result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukxTI.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove field 'fax' from the list,

*.xml

```
   <div t-field="o.partner_id"
                         t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone"], "no_marker": true}'/>
```

Comment: if I use this line.It should hide? I want to hide fax on print view

Comment: Yes. You just try it.

Comment: Please see my changes I have fax in div.I put.but  not worked

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: not working..I am using only xml file which i showed you.please check anything wrong.

Comment: Update your question with the screenshot of latest output.

Comment: updated my code and image here fax is Återförsäljare 20%

Comment: I think the above code has worked. In the image, the fax field has been removed from first Customer `Customer Addresswww`. You need to find out where is the second customer address come from? (I mean the code). Make the same change in that partner field too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `fax` attribute from `t-options` and you can achieve that by inheriting the original template and overriding `<div t-field="o.partner_id"...` element.

```
<template id="custom_report_picking" inherit_id="stock.report_picking">
    <xpath expr="//t/t/t/t/div/div/div/div[2]/div" position="replace">
            <div t-field="o.partner_id"
                 t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone"], "no_marker": true}'/>
        </xpath>
</template>
```